# Fuzzy search using Lucene with Azure Search .NET SDK

Tags: c#, lucene, azure-cognitive-search, fuzzy-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am trying to use Fuzzy search in combination with partial search and match boosting, using the Azure Search .NET API.

This is what I currently have, it doesn't work yet:

```
// Create SearchIndexClient
searchIndexClient= new SearchIndexClient("searchServiceName", "indexName", [credentials]);
// Set search params
var searchParameters = new SearchParameters(
                includeTotalResultCount: true,
                queryType: QueryType.Full);
// Set search string
string searchText = "elise*~^10";
// perform search.
var result = searchIndexClient.Documents.SearchAsync(searchText, searchParameters);
```

There is an entry in that index with a property Name with value 'Elyse'. This entry is not found using the above code. If i change the searchText to `"elyse~"`, the entry does get returned.

I also could not get this to work in the Azure web portal search explorer (does that thing have a name?).

What am I missing here?
I think it may be an issue with escaping, but I am not sure how to fix it.
I looked at a bunch of documentation and Stack Overflow questions on the topic, but none showed a complete answer on how to make a fuzzy search call using the .NET SDK. So please respond in the form of complete code if possible. 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't compiled your application code but it looks correct. The issue here is that wildcard queries don't work with fuzzy operator as you are expecting it to work here.

There is a note in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_wildcard) that says:

> You cannot use a * or ? symbol as the first character of a search. **No
>   text analysis is performed on wildcard search queries.** At query time,
>   wildcard query terms are compared against analyzed terms in the search
>   index and expanded.

This means that specifying a fuzzy operator after a wildcard doesn't have any affect and the result is the same as not applying it. In your example, `elise*~^10` is effectively `elise*^10` and therefore doesn't match "elyse".

One way to express this as in a query is to use OR operator. `elise~^10 OR elise*^10`. This will return the doc containing "elyse" because of the 1st clause.

Comment: Thanks for answering, even if it is days after I posted the question. We have decided to use build partial & fuzzy search in code, without using the functionality of Azure Congnitive Search. This way we can combine partial and fuzzy search and we have more control.